# how to copy a ntfs filesystem drive on open-suse

Tags: linux, opensuse

i need to reformat a windows drive but i want to keep the old one, i have a 2Tb removable hard drive to copy the old one to but i can't open the old drive or do anything with it on my copy of open suse. it just says failure to read ntfs. i am new to Linux so i don't know what i am doing anyone know how i can copy this? any questions ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dd` to copy the entire partition into a file.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/media/storage/harddrive.ntfs bs=32M
```

Comment: Uhh do i change anything? like put the drives name in? and where to put it?

Comment: You'll have to point `if` at the appropriate device node to read from, and `of` at the filename you want to store the image in. As always, `man` is your friend.

Comment: so like dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=FreeAgent GoFlex/oldharddrive/harddrive.ntfs bs=32M (sorry idk how to do "if" one the harddrive is named frost and my new harddrive is "freeagent goflex" and i want it in file oldharddrive)

Comment: Running `fdisk -l` as root will let you see all partitions on all drives, which can help you pick out the value for `if`. The space in your `of` will need to be escaped somehow. `of='FreeAgent GoFlex/oldharddrive/harddrive.ntfs'`

Comment: Absolute path to 'fdisk' is '/sbin/fdisk', so running it may require superuser privileges (eg. root). sorry i am really noob with linux :| i ran fdish -1 but what do i do with it